# Preg_match_all() - Regular expression is too large

Tags: php, mysql, regex

How could I improve the following `preg_match_all` pattern, so I don't have this Warning:

> preg_match_all(): Compilation failed: regular expression is too large at offset 32036

```php
    $sql = "SELECT skills FROM weighted_skills_industry 
    WHERE industry = 'Engineering' ORDER by LENGTH(skills) DESC LIMIT 3000";

    $result = $con->query($sql); 
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

         $skill[] = $row['skills'];

      }
        $pattern = '~(?<![\w-])(?:' . implode('|', array_map(function($i) { return preg_quote($i, '~'); }, $skill)) . ')(?![\w-])~i';

        if (preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matchWords)) {

          //write something
        }
```

Comment: What is contained in `$skill` ?

Comment: $skills are keywords and are from a database, there can be thousands of them. I then use them to find a match in $text.

Comment: I would suggest doing this comparison in your database then, _not_ in PHP.  If you can rephrase your question to better explain how the relevant database table is connected to `$skill`, maybe someone can give you a workaround.

Comment: Thanks I've added the database part.

Comment: I have no idea of what you're trying to do but you seem to be packing every DB row into a huge single string and then running a regular expression search on it. Is your search something that cannot be done on individual rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you're grabbing a list of skills (as an array of keywords) from your DB and are looking to check if the string `$text` contains any of these words.

What you're using right now is probably the way to go, but I doubt you can make your regular expression shorter if you have thousands of these words.

You could simply loop over the keywords and perform the regex check on each. This is quite a bit slower, but lets you break the loop whenever any of the words has been found (if desired):

```
foreach ($skills as $skill) {
  if (preg_match('~(?<![\w-])(?:' . preg_quote($skill, '~') . ')(?![\w-])~i', $text, $matches)) {
    // do stuff with $matches[0] (found keyword)
    // ...
    break; // <- if finding one of these words is enough
  }
}
```

Note that you can also use `\b` in regexes to check for word boundaries. Consider:

```
\bword\b
```

instead of:

```
(?<![\w-])word(?![\w-])
```

Alternatively, there are ways to [increase the pattern size limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31172837/regular-expression-is-too-large-error-in-php), but you'll have to recompile PHP.

Comment: Great, this works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I might use the following query instead:

```
SELECT skills
FROM weighted_skills_industry 
WHERE
    industry = 'Engineering' AND
    skills REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]]', ?, '[[:>:]]')
ORDER BY
    LENGTH(skills) DESC
LIMIT 3000;
```

To the `?` placeholder, you can bind the `$text` variable from your PHP code.  The above logic would return every skill which can be found inside the text.

Comment: Thanks, but I couldn't get the skills from your code. I'm not an experienced developer so although your solution is probably best, I just want to improve the pattern in my question for the time being - otherwise it's going to take me weeks to study your solution and implement it.

Comment: @Seb All I am doing is performing the regex check for each skill against your text in the actual MySQL database, rather than trying to do this from the PHP code.  There are other ways to workaround your problem, but this is what I would probably do.