# How to match whole word only in Preg_match_all in PHP, Compilation failed

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have asked a similar question [Preg_match_all() - Regular expression is too large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59552096/preg-match-all-regular-expression-is-too-large?noredirect=1#comment105276634_59552096)
  but still the accepted answer doesn't fulfil my needs.

The answer suggest this regex:

```
foreach ($skills as $skill) {
  if (preg_match('~(?<![\w-])(?:' . preg_quote($skill, '~') . ')(?![\w-])~i', $text, $matches)) {
    // do stuff with $matches[0] (found keyword)
    // ...
    break; // <- if finding one of these words is enough
  }
}
```

$skills = thousands of skills from a DBA.
$text = any text, in general about 800 words.

e.g. with this $text = "I'm a .net developer with good communication skills and know java";

**The above regex would echo:**

communication skills
 communication
 skills
.net developer
.net
developer
java

**While I just want (as long as a skill exist):** communication skills, .net developer, java.

For that I have the regex below, which gives me the expected results, but I have the following error:

> preg_match_all(): Compilation failed: regular expression is too large
> at offset 32036

```
$pattern = '~(?<![\w-])(?:' . implode('|', array_map(function($i) { return preg_quote($i, '~'); }, $skill)) . ')(?![\w-])~i';

        if (preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matchWords)) {

          //write something
        }
```

So how can I improve the regex above to give me the expected results: *communication skills* only?

There are some answers here [“Regular Expression is too large” error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31172837/regular-expression-is-too-large-error-in-php)

The below might be a solution, but I don't understand how to implement it, if someone could please explain or let me know the best way to achieve the expected results. Many Thanks.

*Split your regular expression at | and process the resulting sub-expressions separately. If the regex is essentially numerous keywords separated by |, then converting to a strtok or a loop with strpos may be a better & faster choice.*

Answer (score 0):

I do not see, why you would need regexp for this. Since you want to match single words, you may simply use `strpos` like this:

```
foreach ($skills as $skill) {
  $pos = strpos($text, $skill);
  if ($pos !== -1) {
    $match = substr($text, $pos, strlen($skill));
    // do stuff with $matches (found keyword)
    // ...
    break; // <- if finding one of these words is enough
  }
}
```

Note that you would have to use `mb_*` functions if you have to deal with mulitbyte words.

Comment: Thanks, but your answer only returns one match. $text can contains up to 800 keywords. So if a skill is in $text, it should be echoed too e.g. $text = ".net communication skills java developer". Expected results: .net, communication skills, java.

Comment: This will not respect wordboundaries, right? I mean `cat` will match `communication`.

Comment: @mickmackusa Correct - you could add the wordboundary to the `$skill`, but in this case the solution of Seb is better, so I would recommend using this.