# Define character classes once and use them multiple times

Tags: regex

In a regular expression I use twice a character classes with about 2000 unicodes.

I compose the regular expression in the application.

```
$regEx = sprintf(
    '/(?P<block>([%s])(?P<sub1>[%s]+)([%s](?P<sub2>[%s]+))?)/u',
    Config::START_CHARACTERS_REGEX, // $
    Config::ALLOW_UNICODES_REGEX, // ~2000 Unicodes
    Config::SEPARATOR_REGEX, // #
    Config::ALLOW_UNICODES_REGEX // ~2000 Unicodes
);

Example: „$⊇∅∪⊈≦∏#≥≽∮⨖⨚“

block: $⊇∅∪⊈≦∏#≥≽∮⨖⨚
sub1: ⊇∅∪⊈≦∏
sub2: ≥≽∮⨖⨚
```

I get the error: Compilation failed: regular expression is too large at offset 165362.

The problem is that I cannot use Unicode blocks.

I could shorten the regex, define it only once in the character classes but use it twice, i.e. define it once in the regular expression and then reference it.

Is this possible? I cannot find anything in this regard.

Comment: And where is you code that produces "Compilation failed" ?

Comment: If you are programming in PHP, the answer is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31172837/regular-expression-is-too-large-error-in-php

Comment: @Luuk Thanks for the hint. I think I found the solution there. My first test: Number: **256** and RegEx `(?(DEFINE)(?'subroutine'[0-9]+))(?P>subroutine)` --> Match: **256**